# Duplicate primary key appears with SELECT INTO. SQL Agent job

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, primary-key

An agent job, that usually runs extremely reliably, failed just now, with a rather unexpected error. It was complaining because it found a duplicate primary key where, as far as I can tell, no duplicate could possibly exist.
FWIW The database is a replication subscriber.

**Obfuscated details:**
Here's the agent notification.

```
-----Original Message-----
From: SQL Notification Service 
Sent: Tuesday, 12 February 2019 12:30 PM
To: My SQL Notification Service <blah@blahblah.org>
Subject: [The job failed.] SQL Server Job System: 'Blah Populate Blah Table' completed on \\BLAH.

JOB RUN:    'Blah Populate Blah Table' was run on 12/02/2019 at 12:30:00 PM
DURATION:   0 hours, 0 minutes, 1 seconds
STATUS:     Failed
MESSAGES:   The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 1029 (Occurs every day every 15 minute(s)).  The last step to run was step 1 (Run UspGetBlah).
```

Here’s the error:

```
/*Date      2019/02/12 12:30:00 PM
Log     Job History (Blah Populate Blah Table)

Step ID     1
Server      BLAH
Job Name        Blah Populate Blah Table
Step Name       Run UspGetBlah
Duration        00:00:01
Sql Severity    16
Sql Message ID  3621
Operator Emailed    
Operator Net sent   
Operator Paged  
Retries Attempted   0

Message
Executed as user: BLAH\svc_SQLBLAH. 
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.#blah_00000028C5C5' and the index name 'ix_0x01ef45'. 
The duplicate key value is (2233040). [SQLSTATE 23000] (Error 1505)  The statement has been terminated. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 3621).  The step failed.
*/
```

Here’s the code from the stored procedure that generated the error. Note that there’s a primary key constraint (`blah_id`) on `dbo.blah`:

```
  declare @now as datetime = getdate()
;
       if object_id('tempdb..#blah') is not null
     drop table #blah;
   select blah.blah_id --This is the PK
          ,blah.person_id
          ,blah.start_dttm
          ,case when blah.end_flag = 'n' 
                     then blah.end_dttm 
            end                                                 as end_dttm
          ,case when blah.end_flag = 'n' 
                     and blah.end_dttm is not null 
                     then blah.location_id 
            end                                                 as location_id
     into #blah
     from dbo.blah                   blah
    where blah.warning_flag = 'n'
          and blah.start_flag = 'n' 
          and (blah.end_dttm is null
               or blah.end_dttm > @now - 20 
               or blah.end_flag = 'y'
              )
          and blah.site_id in('221','331')
;
   create unique clustered index ix_0x01ef45 on #blah (blah_id)
;
```

Any suggestions on how this could be possible? Oh, and I can't reproduce it!

**EDIT** DDL of the source table as requested below (I've renamed fields for IP reasons, and chopped out any irrelevant fields):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BLAH](
    [BLAH_ID] [numeric](10, 0) IDENTITY(500000,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [PERSON_ID] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
    [LOCATION_ID] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
    [SITE_ID] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
    start_dttm [datetime] NOT NULL,
    end_dttm [datetime] NULL,
    start_flag char(1) NOT NULL,
    end_flag char(1) NOT NULL,
    warning_flag char(1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [CPK_BLAH] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [BLAH_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON
    , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
    , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
    , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
    , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [INDEX]
GO
```

Comment: Based on your explanation, no idea how it is possible. So there must be more to it... some other process also adding data? A more complicated select statement? Not the table you expect (is there some kind of dynamic naming going on with that table suffix?)

Comment: Are you really inserting into a temporary table? Because if it really is a temporary table, it will only be be accessible in the session it was created, so we can rule out simultaneous insert attempts from two different sessions - and if it's not a temporary table, that's most likely the explanation for this select into - as this select statement it self can't produce duplicate values of the primary key (or any other unique column in `dbo.blah` for that matter.

Comment: zohar-peled It's a local temporary table exactly as described. 
nick-mcdermaid There is nothing more to the statement than what you see. I do wonder if it's something to do with replication activity. The job is running against the subscriber. The application logs activity and it seems as though the row was being updated at the same time as the job was trying to run. The only thing I changed in the above messages, was the name of the objects (eg changed to *blah*). I know it's weird, that's why I posted the question.

Comment: Can you provide DDLs of a table and primary key? This situation can be possible or because you have compound primary key or you have got into some bug of the data engine, which is less likely..

Comment: The other question, is READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level used?

Comment: DDL added. READ UNCOMMITTED not explicitly used, but I'm wondering now whether this can be set as a default at the database (or worse, server) level?

Comment: nick-mcdermaid the "dynamic naming going on with that table suffix" is related to the way SQL Server names temp tables in tempdb. If I call a local temp table #chickens, in tempdb it's named somthing like dbo.#chickens_____________________________000000123456 presumably to disambiguate it from all the other #chicken local temp tables that might be in use in other sessions. I just chopped out all the underscores - sorry for the confusion :-)